# Using ave() in R

Tags: r, for-loop, count, criteria

I want to count occurrences that match two criteria and assign that value to a cell (is cell the right word here?). So far, I've tried using `nrow()` and `subset()` to do the job, like so:

```
for (n in nrow(data)) {data[n,17] <- nrow(subset(data,(REP == data$REP[n]) & (Was.Sent. == "Sent")))/nrow(subset(data,REP == data$REP[n]))}
```

So far though, each cell is populating as "NA." What am I doing wrong, and is there a better/easier way to do this?

Comment: For starters, try `for (n in 1:nrow(data)) {...}`

Comment: Thanks - that helped, but didn't completely resolve the issue. I'll keep fiddling.

Comment: While posting your code, as you did, is very helpful, it is also good to post sample data so we can try it out. Additionally, you might say a bit about what you were trying to accomplish in the first place. There may be better ways to do this in R than you may have have considered.

Comment: You may want to change the title of this question since you accepted an answer that doesn't use the `subset` function

Comment: I think the point @RichardScriven was trying to make is that your title should briefly describe the problem you're tying to solve since you're open to a solution using any function, not specifically `subset`.

Comment: This question has earned a close vote from me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like for every row, you could like to calculate the average number of sent items for the REP in the row. That actually can be better accomplished with the `ave()` function.

Here's a sample data set

```
data <- data.frame(
    Was.Sent=c("Sent","No")[c(1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1)],
    REP=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2)
)
```

And here's the code that will add a new column with the desired percent

```
data$psent<-with(data, ave(Was.Sent=="Sent", REP, FUN=mean))
```

And if I view the results, I see

```
cbind(data,psent)[order(data$REP, data$Was.Sent),]
#  Was.Sent REP     psent
#7       No   1 0.6666667
#1     Sent   1 0.6666667
#4     Sent   1 0.6666667
#5       No   2 0.6666667
#2     Sent   2 0.6666667
#8     Sent   2 0.6666667
#3       No   3 0.5000000
#6     Sent   3 0.5000000
```

Comment: Wow... that's quite a powerful function. Worked like a charm - thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the values in the new column.  They are percentages of what? "The average number of sent items for REP in the row" isn't clear to me.

Comment: @RichardScriven For the Rep in each row, calculate the total number of items in the data he sent and divide that by the total number of items in the data he did or did not send. Rep 1 had 2 "sent", 1 "no"; so his value is 2/(2+1) Rep three had one of each so 50% of all his actions were sent. I'm using the fact that `==` results in `TRUE/FALSE` which when converted to numeric values are `1/0`. This so For Rep 1, we are taking `mean(c(1,1,0))` and for Rep 3 we are taking `mean(c(0,1))` to calculate the proportions.

Comment: Okay, but the proportion of "No" Sent when REP is 1 is not 66.7% , it's 33.3%. This entire post is confusing I guess. Wouldn't `table(data)` give us a good idea of the "uncalculated" proportions?

Comment: So ave() is working great, but I don't really understand quite how it works. I perused the web for some info, but it was sparse. If you want to give me the run down on how the function works, that'd be really helpful.

Comment: @userNaN. `ave()` is a lot like `tapply()` but instead of just returning one value per factor level, it returns a vector the same length as the input, the a value generated by applying the requested `FUN` to only the the values corresponding to one factor level at a time. So in that way it is like the `by()` function in that it partitions the data before applying the requested function, but it reassembles them in the original order for you as well.